# Angular 6 problem with checking localstorage on app init

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, local-storage, angular6

I have problem with checking on page load if user is logged in app or no. I tried with eventEmmiter and Subject but on load there is not result for checking in local storage.

This is my AuthenticationService

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  constructor() {
  }
  // here is bunch of code

  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    let currentUser = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
    return !!(currentUser);
  }
```

}

and this is my HedaerComponent:

```
constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
 this.checkUser();
}

checkUser() {
 if (this.authenticationService.isLoggedIn()) {
 // do something
 }
 else {
 // do something
 }
}
```

I have problem with first loading of app, how can I check if user i logged or not? As I sad I try with emmiting value but with no results. Thanks for help!

Comment: This should work. If it doesn't, please provide a [mcve] reproducing the issue.

Comment: Where this header component is accessed. in index,html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with adding new service, here is example

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

class CustomEventEmitter extends Subject<any>{
 constructor() {
    super();
 }
 emit(value: any) {
    super.next(value);
 }
}

export class PubSubService {
 Stream: CustomEventEmitter;
 constructor() {
    this.Stream = new CustomEventEmitter;
 }
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular's route guard to achieve that. Here's some tutorial:

1. https://ryanchenkie.com/angular-authentication-using-route-guards
2. https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Comment: Not an answer, but usefull advice.

Answer (score 0):

It should help

```
 let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
```